# File operation in ctypes module

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, ctypes

I have written a file `a.c` which is having a function `func_open` which does file open and returns.

I have made it an `.so` file so I can import to Python using `ctypes`.

When I call `func_open()` from Python control is entering into `a.c` function  `func_open()` but I am getting an error: "open: No such file or directory".

**a.c**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int func_open(void)
{
    open("./a.c",O_RDWR);
    perror("open");
    return 0;
}
```

Python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('./libmystuff.so.1.0.1')
print "Open: ",testlib.func_open(),"\n"
```

Comment: but it is working in Python prompt not in  script file.
does somebody know the reason please.

Thanks PSR.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be passing file path to func_open as it expects a.c to be in working directory of python or directory where libmystuff.so.1.0.1 is placed.

To verify if file open is working put libmystuff.so.1.0.1, python file, a.c file at same location.

Comment: I am having Every file in same path(directory) it is not working